# Is there a way to catch exceptions thrown within flattenMerge()?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

[Playground sample](https://pl.kotl.in/chvzi5JaV)

Given this code, the exception thrown in `getRecords()` is not caught in `testFlattenMerge()` - should it not be catchable though? Also, in `getPeople()`, the exception can be caught which causes `flattenMerge()` to work as expected, but it prints out *"Caught in people"* before any numbers are printed, and not after 64, as I expected. Is this the correct behavior? I can't quite fit my mental model of `flattenMerge()` around this.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun getRecords(id: Int) = flow {
    repeat(5) { emit("A record for $id") }
    if (id == 6) throw RuntimeException("Anything but #6!")
    repeat(5) { emit("A record for $id") }
}

fun getPeople() = flow {
    repeat(10) { emit(getRecords(it)) }
    // repeat(10) { emit(getRecords(it).catch{ println("Caught in getPeople()")}) } // This works, but it prints /before/ any cnt lines...?
}

suspend fun testFlattenMerge() {
    println ("Merge with flattenMerge()")
    var cnt = 0
    val flowOfFlows = getPeople()
    flowOfFlows.catch{ println("Caught before flattenMerge")}
        .flattenMerge()
        .catch{ println("Caught after flattenMerge")}
        .collect {
            println("${cnt++}") // Without catching inside getPeople() this stops at 64
        }
}

suspend fun testManualMerge() {
    println("Merge manually")
    var cnt = 0    
    repeat(10) {
        getRecords(it).catch{ println("Caught in manual merge") }
            .collect {
                println("${cnt++}") // This goes up to 94, as expected
            }
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    testFlattenMerge()
    testManualMerge()
}
```

Comment: `Flow` is still ironing out the exception-handling behavior, there are several open issues about it. I guess this is one more of them, maybe worth raising an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues) or checking the existing ones. I suppose 64 comes up because it's an internal batch size.

Comment: The 64 is expected based on my contrived example. (it throws by chance after 64 emits) I will post on GitHub if needed!